# shell script to fetch the latest modified file of format ABC_*_DATA_*.zip from ftp site (windows) to target server(Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, shell, ftp, last-modified

I tried the below but its not actually picking the latest file. Appreciate your help !!!

```
ls -rt|find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'ABC_*_DATA_*.zip'|tail -n 1
```

~TIA

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `find` here, just use `ls` with `tail`

```
ls -lt ABC_*_DATA_*.zip | head -n 1
```

Comment: Its not helping as the ftp site is a windows platform. its bring the latest modified .txt file. ANy advise ?

Comment: You already had `ls` command in your question. Is ls not working or `ls -lt` not working?